# Working with a function that returns an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have written a function in Javascipt that returns a variable sized array. How do I declare/assign a variable in the calling function to accept this array and perform further processing on it?

```
function myArrayFunction()
{
    const myArray = [];             //Initialise Empty Array
    var x = 0;                      //Array index (cannot use .push() function in my app)
    
    for (let i = 0 ; i < 6 ; i++) {
        myArray[x] = i * 2;         //Simple function that doubles i and assigns value to index in array
    }
    return myArray;                 //Should return a 6 element array
}

const myOtherArray = [];            //The array for the value returned from myArrayFunction() to be stored in

myOtherArray = myArrayFunction();
```

I get a warning the Debugging Scripts.array declaration error: invalid assignment to const `myOtherArray'. What's wrong?

I have tried using the const, let and var key words to initialise an empty array value.

I was expecting the variable that is passed out of the function would be assigned to the variable within the calling function.

### Updated Code

Here is updated code, which includes a console.log statement enclosed in a second for loop. The result I expect is that the function should loop back through myArray and print out each of the elements at its 6 index locations.

```js
function myArrayFunction()
{
  const myArray = [];     //Initialise Empty Array
  var x = 0;              //Array index (

  for (let i = 0 ; i < 6 ; i++) {
    myArray[x] = i * 2;   //Simple function  
  }
   for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) { //Loop through array
       console.log(myArray[x]);  
   }
  return myArray;         //Should return a 6 element array
}

let myOtherArray = [];    //The array to store returned array

myOtherArray = myArrayFunction();

console.log(myOtherArray);
```

When I run this code, I do not see an array of 6 numbers, but only the last one (10)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask].  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: *"When I try to access the array (for debugging purposes) I get a warning the cassifierIDArray is not defined?"* Assuming that typo is just in your text and not your code (you've missed out the `l` in `classifier`, but only in that text), the code shown will not produce that error. Please reduce the problem to a [mre] and post the code for the MRE to the question. I don't think your question is specifically TypeScript-related, so you can use the Stack Snippets mplugjan pointed you at with type annotations commented out. Alternatively, use https://www.typescriptlang.org/play but include the...

Comment: ...full code **in** the question as well, and beware of [this bug](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/386543/why-does-my-typescript-playground-link-break-when-i-use-insert-hyperlink) with playground links (you can use https://tsplay.dev to work around it).

Comment: The code as posted should work. I don't see how'd it could possibly give you an undefined for the `classifierIDArray` at that point.

Comment: You're just updating index 0 of your array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that using the .push() function to create the array solves the problem

```js
function myArrayFunction()
{
        const myArray = [];             //Initialise Empty Array
        var x = 0;                      //Array index (cannot use .push() function in my app)
        var y = 0;                      //The initial value of the array
        
        for (let i = 0 ; i < 6 ; i++) {
            y = i * 2;
            myArray.push(y);            //push the answer onto array
            console.log("Value of myArray = " + myArray[i]);
        }
            
        return myArray;                 //Should return a 6 element array
}
```

It seems the error I am getting is not related to the Javascipt I had written, but rather the environment in which I am trying to execute it (Sparx Enterprise Architect). I will post on a more specialised forum and see if anyone has any ideas. Thanks all

Comment: If the environment you're running it in doesn't allow you to use `push`, you can still do direct assignment like you were trying. Just change the `myArray.push(y)` line to `myArray[i] = y`, and the result is identical.

Comment: Another thing to watch out for that might be messing things up in your original code, is the use of `var`. Try switching all uses of `var` to `let`. `var` has some complexity associated with it called variable hoisting, which might be causing unexpected problems in your original code.

Answer (score -1):

<s>You have a typo in the variable name of `Session.Output(classiferIDArray[0]);` causing the `classiferIDArray is not defined` error.</s>

With your code updated, the output is a bunch of 10s because you're trying to use `x` as the index, but actually using `i` as the index in the for loop. I.e. `x` is always `0`, and after the first for loop runs, the `0th` entry in `myArray` is set to `5 * 2`. Then you log that value a bunch of times in your next for loop.

Comment: Hi, yes you're right! Although after providing a simplified code snippet (without the typo) the error persists!

Comment: @JohnGladstone I made it runnable by adding snippet comments, and added a logging line at the end, and it doesn't give the error.

Comment: What is this answer? It has nothing to do with tha question. There is no Session.Output anywhere.

Comment: Hi @qwerty_so, I ameded the code to make it simpler to understand. The answer applied to the old code snippet.

Comment: It seems that I am not creating an array in the first For Loop?

Comment: If you changed the question's content, then you should adapt the answer. As it is, they are not fit.

Comment: @JohnGladstone Updated my answer to reflect question changes.